# Jelly script <j:if> comparison of two strings

Tags: if-statement, jelly

All,
Simply, I need to compare two strings within a jelly script and if they are not the same, I want to update one string with the other value.  Simply, I'd like something like this:

```
     <j:if test="${currentTestName} != ${trTest_Name_Pass}">
         <j:set var="currentTestName" value="${trTest_Name_Pass}"/>
     </j:if>
```

I've tried various test conditions such as

```
     <j:if test="!( ${currentTestName.equals('${trTest_Name_Pass}')} )">
         <j:set var="currentTestName" value="${trTest_Name_Pass}"/>
     </j:if>
```

and some other combinations, but I'm stymied to see how to compare the strings.  I've done a fair amount of searching, but have not hit on a solution.  Maybe Jelly does not support this.  In any case, apologies if this has been addressed elsewhere, but I seemed to have missed it, if it was.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.  -- JC

Comment: Have you tried `test="!( ${currentTestName.equals('trTest_Name_Pass')}`

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  In this case, "trTest_Name_Pass" is another variable, so I need to have it resolve out to the variable value.  I think your suggestion would compare the value of variable "${currentTestName}" to the string "trTest_Name_Pass" and not to the variable in "${trTest_Name_Pass}".  This snippet is from a JUnit result which is looping through passing tests, so I only want to display the base name of the test once and then change it to the next test name when its set of tests are being displayed.

Comment: Sorry, I've meant `test="!( ${currentTestName.equals(trTest_Name_Pass)}`. Can you test that?

Comment: Hi Lajos,  Unfortunately, that did not appear to resolve the problem.  This is what I used.   "<j:if test="!( ${currentTestName.equals(trTest_Name_Pass)} )">
   <li>Inside IF statement</li>
   <j:set var="currentTestName" value="${trTest_Name_Pass}"/>
</j:if>"   The <li> will act as a debug statement in the output, however it does not fall into this block at the correct time.  I do think that somehow I need to de-reference the trTest_Name_Pass variable.  Or, figure out another jelly syntax for comparing strings.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the syntax of the [Jelly if tag](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jelly/tags.html#core:if) to:

```
<j:if test="${currentTestName != trTest_Name_Pass}">
```

Or to:

```
<j:if test="${!currentTestName.equals(trTest_Name_Pass)}">
```